# Summing rows in Access based upon previous row

Tags: sql, database, ms-access

Basically I have an Access query set to return all entries on a given date. On that date, there are "catch all" entries (Called 'Hourly') that just say when a one-hour observation window was started. Then, if there is anything observed in that hour, it is entered with a unique ID, like below.

```
| Date       | Time  | ID      | Amount |
|------------|-------|---------|--------|
| 11/14/2017 | 10:30 | Hourly  | 0      |
| 11/14/2017 | 10:34 | Unique1 | 1      |
| 11/14/2017 | 10:46 | Unique2 | 1      |
| 11/14/2017 | 11:17 | Unique1 | 1      |
| 11/14/2017 | 11:30 | Hourly  | 0      |
| 11/14/2017 | 11:49 | Unique1 | 1      |
| 11/14/2017 | 12:30 | Hourly  | 0      |
| 11/14/2017 | 12:43 | Unique1 | 1      |
| 11/14/2017 | 12:51 | Unique1 | 1      |
| 11/14/2017 | 13:01 | Unique2 | 1      |
```

We want to put out hour summaries based on the ID 'Hourly', where all further entries are combined/summed into that one 'Hourly' ID, like the following:

```
Date        Time     ID   Amount
11/14/2017  10:30   Hourly  3
11/14/2017  11:30   Hourly  1
11/14/2017  12:30   Hourly  3
```

We've tried summing the entries based upon the hour field of the time, however it ends up looking like:

```
 Date        Hour     Amount
11/14/2017    10        2
11/14/2017    11        2
11/14/2017    12        2
11/14/2017    13        1
```

Unfortunately, when running statistics on this output, the hourly average would be 1.75/hour, when in reality it's 2.33/hr.

Is there a way to specify that If an entry is 'Hourly', then sum all entries until the next 'Hourly' entry? Or any other ideas that would get us to a similar place?

Thank you!

Comment: Have a look at [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: You want to group entries by every x:30-y:30 period or by everything between two "hourly" rows?

Comment: Unfortunately, the "hourly" rows sometimes start at x:00, others at x:30. So I thought everything between two "hourly" rows would be a workaround.

Comment: Are date and time stored inside a single field?

Comment: They are not, although I could make that happen if it'd help!

Answer (score 1):

*I assumed that the date and time are stored inside a single Date/Time field. If this is not the case then you have to adjust accordingly.*

I created the following two "queries" in MS Access 2007:

```
/* testdata_daterange */
SELECT a.Date as D1, Min(b.Date) AS D2
FROM testdata AS a
LEFT JOIN testdata AS b ON (a.Date < b.Date and b.id='Hourly')
WHERE a.id='Hourly'
GROUP BY a.Date;

/* testdata_sum */
SELECT testdata_daterange.D1, testdata_daterange.D2, SUM(Amount) AS Total
FROM testdata
INNER JOIN testdata_daterange ON (testdata_daterange.D1 <= testdata.Date) AND (testdata.Date < testdata_daterange.D2 or testdata_daterange.D2 is null)
WHERE testdata.ID<>'Hourly'
GROUP BY testdata_daterange.D1, testdata_daterange.D2;
```

And result:

[image: Output]

Answer (score -1):

The following isn't the best code, but may help to get you started:

```
Function SummariseHourly()
    Dim dbsCdb As DAO.Database
    Dim rstInp As DAO.Recordset
    Dim rstOut As DAO.Recordset
    Dim lngAmt As Long
    Dim flgEnd As Boolean

    Set dbsCdb = CurrentDb
    Set rstInp = dbsCdb.OpenRecordset("SELECT * FROM InputTable ORDER BY Date, Time")
    Set rstOut = dbsCdb.OpenRecordset("OutputTable")

    If Not rstInp.EOF Then ' If there are records in the Input Table
        rstInp.MoveFirst ' Move to the first one
        Do Until rstInp.EOF ' Whilst there are still records in the Input Table
            If rstInp!id = "Hourly" Then ' If the "ID" of the current record is "Hourly"
                rstOut.AddNew ' Add a new record to the Output Table
                rstOut!Date = rstInp!Date ' Populate the "Date"
                rstOut!Time = rstInp!Time ' Populate the "Time"
                rstOut!id = "Hourly" ' Populate the "ID"
                rstInp.MoveNext ' Move onto the next record
                lngAmt = 0 ' Initialise a variable to store the total of "Amount"
                flgEnd = False ' Initialise a variable to cease the inner loop
                Do Until rstInp.EOF Or flgEnd ' Whilst there are still records
                    If rstInp!id = "Hourly" Then ' If the "ID" is "Hourly"
                        flgEnd = True ' Exit the loop
                    Else
                        lngAmt = lngAmt + rstInp!Amount ' Else add the "Amount" stored with the record to our total
                        rstInp.MoveNext ' Move onto the next record
                    End If
                Loop
                rstOut!Amount = lngAmt ' Populate the "Amount" in the new record with our total
                rstOut.Update ' Update the Output Table with the new record
            Else
                rstInp.MoveNext ' Else we haven't reached an "Hourly" record yet
            End If
        Loop
    End If

    rstInp.Close
    rstOut.Close
End Function
```

The code assumes that your data resides in a table called `"InputTable"` and that there exists a table with the same structure called `"OutputTable"`.